# Does C# create weird newlines with verbatim strings?

Tags: c#, sql, enterprise-library

I was running a personal test to try and understand EnterpriseLibrary. I was doing an inline SQL query:

```
string query = @"USE Database
                 SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
                 SELECT * FROM table
                 WHERE table.column = 'sample'"
```

Database, table, and column's names have been changed from their originals

However when executing this query, I received

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near 'USE'.
```

Thinking that my syntax was wrong, I copied this query into SQL Server and it worked. I then thought that the verbatim string syntax was causing problems...so I used

```
string query = "USE Database " +
               "SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED " +
               "SELECT * FROM table " +
               "WHERE table.column = 'sample'"
```

Lo and behold it worked. I am thinking the verbatim string is inputting a new line that Enterprise Library cannot parse correctly. Am I correct in assuming this? If so, how can I manipulate the verbatim string for this to work?

UPDATE:
Trying `query.Replace("\r\n", "")` It works!

UPDATE 2:
Trying the semicolon delimiter, that also works!

The mysteries of Enterprise Library...

Why does the semicolon delimiter work?

Comment: With verbatim string you will get line breaks as well as spaces as specified in your original string. So your string would look like `USE Database \r\n space(s) SET TRANSACTION.......`

Comment: I think Verbatims translate the newline as \r\n, and my best guess is that the SQL parser takes newlines only as \n, but don't quote me, let me research a bit before giving you an answer.

Comment: Try outputting the query after you have set the verbatim string. You might be able to see what escape chars \r\n etc it does not like...it could be adding in something weird for spaces.

Comment: Does your update, "will post results," mean that removing the newlines resulted in the query working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Verbatim string will add the new line character and all the extra spaces as specified in your query. So for your string you will get:

[image]

So your string would look like `USE Database \r\n space(s) SET TRANSACTION.......`

See: [String C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228362.aspx)

> Because verbatim strings preserve new line characters as part of the
>   string text, they can be used to initialize multiline strings.

Not really sure why Enterprise library doesn't consider it as a valid SQL, you can use `;` to separate statements and then try like:

```
string query = @"USE Database;
                 SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
                 SELECT * FROM table
                 WHERE table.column = 'sample';";
```

Or if you want to replace new line characters from your string then you can do:

```
query = query.Replace("\r\n", "");
```

Comment: But why isn't that valid SQL?

Comment: @Servy, it is a valid SQL, but I guess the issue is with Enterprise libarary. May be adding statement terminator `;` would resolve the issue

Comment: If that is the problem then it wouldn't explain why the non-verbatim string worked for the OP.

Comment: @Servy, using `;` worked for the OP, still not sure why, but I can only assume that Enterprise library doesn't like `\r\n` in un-terminated statements.

Comment: Replacing `\r\n` with an empty string assumes the next line always starts with spaces/tabs (or the previous one ends with spaces/tabs) or else it will cause syntax errors....